# next.js fetch request gives error TypeError: fetch failed

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch-api

I'm setting up a next.js website with strapi but running into an issue with my fetch request. When I make the request in postman I can see the data is returned so the endpoint is correct.

The error I get is `TypeError: fetch failed` in my console I get

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11118:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1337
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
    errno: -111,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 1337
  }
}
```

In my page template, I have

```
import React from "react";

import Layout from "@/components/Layout/Layout";
import { fetcher } from "@/lib/api";

const Insights = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <p>Insights</p>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Insights;

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const insightsResponse = await fetcher(
    "http://localhost:1337/api/insights"
  );
  return {
    props: {
      insights: insightsResponse,
    },
  };
}
```

My fetcher function is

```
export async function fetcher(url: string, options = {}) {
  let response;

  if (!options) {
    response = await fetch(url);
  } else {
    response = await fetch(url, options);
  }

  const data = await response.json();

  return data;
}
```

Comment: check if you are using `https://localhost:3000` instead of `http`. That was the problem for me.

Answer (score 37):

Use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost
it will work

Comment: Use it where exactly?

Comment: Solved it for me. Any explanation to why this is the case? Is there a way to make an alias for the IP to localhost?

Comment: solved for me, but other routes eg sanctum/csrf-token stoped working and started giving error

Comment: @SteveMoretz I added it inside env, Changed it from API_URL=http://localhost:3001 to API_URL=http://127.0.0.1:3001

Answer (score 7):

[reference with video in codegrepper](https://youtu.be/M4ayuBoMxZ8)This error occur because you are  using node version 18 or above where fetch is given by node.
So you have to use node which is below 18 to make fetch work inside
getServerSideProps.you can use nvm to control node version you want to use.

Instead of changing node version you can also give full path to url to fetch instead of /api/listings/property_type give http://localhost:3000/api/listings/property_type

Comment: In my case, I either had to change the node version or I just had to change using `localhost` to using `127.0.0.1`. I'm using Django as my BE in this case.

Source: https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/1624

Comment: I face the same issue in node 16

Comment: I use node 20. Switching to node 16 fix the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same issue when I was trying to build next js 13 full stack app for production (with npx next build). Everything was fine when I was developing it (npx next dev).

Turns out I was calling an api endpoint in the same app in the server component. Front end can’t make a call to a dead server.

Try fetching data right in the server component without calling your own api Get endpoint.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You are correct. Fetching data from a server component to an API route is counter productive since server components ALREADY run on the server.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I used VPN and the error dissapeared.
Maybe, it will help to someone.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue while building a docker image with NextJs. I updated the dockerfile to the latest version from here (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile) and the problem is gone.

Comment: Thank you so much. Adding `ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with node server in my dev env and fixed it using NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 flag running the node server. My GraphQL server is using a self-signed certificate so the issue was related to nodejs issue with the SSL.

Comment: This is insecure

Comment: this is a temp workaround for self-signed certificate localhost only

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i was building a `nextjs(13.4.13)` project for production.
While i was running the build locally with yarn start it was working perfectly fine. But the problem started when i was deploying the project.

Because i upgraded the nextjs from `13.3.4` to `13.4.13` I kept the same dockerfile for building and running the project.

---

The solution was pretty simple:

I just added `ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"` before the line `CMD ["node", "server.js"]` as they state in the official [Dockerfile](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile) for `nextjs`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I changed my packages version and now it works!

I think these days Nextjs app router is going to be stable!!

my old package json:

```
{
  "name": "abdolmaleki-next",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "prisma generate && next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "prebuild": "npx prisma generate"
  },
  "prisma": {
    "seed": "ts-node --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"} prisma/seed.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@liara/cli": "5.0.0",
    "@prisma/client": "5.2.0",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-react": "4.3.0",
    "@types/node": "20.6.0",
    "@types/react": "18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "bcrypt": "5.1.1",
    "eslint": "8.49.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.12",
    "moment-jalaali": "0.10.0",
    "next": "13.4.12",
    "next-auth": "4.23.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "7.46.1",
    "react-hot-toast": "2.4.1",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "3.3.1",
    "sharp": "0.32.6",
    "swiper": "10.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "5.0.0",
    "@types/tinymce": "4.6.6",
    "prisma": "5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1"
  }
}
```

My new package.json :

```
{
  "name": "abdolmaleki-next",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "prisma generate && next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "prebuild": "npx prisma generate"
  },
  "prisma": {
    "seed": "ts-node --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"} prisma/seed.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@liara/cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.3.1",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-react": "^4.3.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "moment-jalaali": "^0.10.0",
    "next": "13.5.4",
    "next-auth": "^4.23.2",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.47.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^3.3.1",
    "sharp": "^0.32.6",
    "swiper": "^10.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/tinymce": "^4.6.6",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.5.4",
    "prisma": "^5.3.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

I suggest you to `npx create-next-app@latest` again.

Answer (score 0):

For Docker, I was trying to fetch from another container and was using Docker Compose. So, changing it to 127.0.0.1 did not help me. I changed the URL to `http://<container_name>:<port>/...` and it worked because this is a server-side request, not a client-side request. Furthermore, when we send a request to localhost, it is sending that request in its own container.

Answer (score -2):

Could you open the Developement tools and check the response code?
I've seen ECONNREFUSED meaning the server is refused this request.
Make sure you are requesting correct data (you can also check it in Network Tab)

Please reference this document
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

The fetch have more options, such as method, headers (headers field is very important), ... Add these request options and try again.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer

Comment: After further debugging it seems it's docker related. I run the app with `yarn start` rather than through docker / devcontainer and it works.