# Flask app.run method does not work with WinPython 3.11.1 and next.js application: fetch failed

Tags: python, flask, debugging, next.js, python-3.11

When using WinPython 3.10.5 I am able to debug my flask & next.js application using the flask debug mode (to enable hot reloads):

```
app.run(debug=True, host=host, port=port)
```

However, when using WinPython 3.11.1, the flask debug mode does not work any more. The fetch command in the static part of my next application fails and I get following error in Google Chrome dev-tools console:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
react-dom.development.js:29840 Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: https://reactjs.org/link/react-devtools
index.js:619 Uncaught TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async apiCall (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/_app.js:30:26)
    at async MyApp.getInitialProps (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/_app.js:34:27)
    at async loadGetInitialProps (file://C:\python_env\workspace\flask_demo\front_end\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\utils.js:146:19)
    at async renderToHTML (file://C:\python_env\workspace\flask_demo\front_end\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:417:13)
    at async doRender (file://C:\python_env\workspace\flask_demo\front_end\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1031:34)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.incrementalCache.incrementalCache (file://C:\python_env\workspace\flask_demo\front_end\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1162:28)
    at async (file://C:\python_env\workspace\flask_demo\front_end\node_modules\next\dist\server\response-cache\index.js:99:36)
getServerError @ client.js:1
eval @ index.js:619
setTimeout (async)
hydrate @ index.js:607
await in hydrate (async)
eval @ next-dev.js:48
Promise.then (async)
eval @ next-dev.js:42
./node_modules/next/dist/client/next-dev.js @ main.js?ts=1684760846398:181
options.factory @ webpack.js?ts=1684760846398:649
__webpack_require__ @ webpack.js?ts=1684760846398:37
__webpack_exec__ @ main.js?ts=1684760846398:1094
(anonymous) @ main.js?ts=1684760846398:1095
webpackJsonpCallback @ webpack.js?ts=1684760846398:1197
(anonymous) @ main.js?ts=1684760846398:9
favicon.ico:1     GET http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

a) If I manually enter the fetched url `http://localhost:5000/api/id_mode` in an extra tab, I get the expected result from the flask application.

b) If I run the flask application with the waitress `serve` function (=without debug mode) instead of using `app.run(...)` , the application works just fine. Therefore, it does not seem to be a JavaScript issue.

```
serve(app, host=host, port=port)
```

Project file structure:

[image]

Python code in **main.py**:

```
import sys
from flask import (
    Flask,
    jsonify
)
from flask_cors import CORS
from waitress import serve

def main():
    # workaround to fix issue with relative path to python in PyCharm for debugging
    # Also see
    # https://gitlab.cc-asp.fraunhofer.de/isi/micat/-/issues/363
    sys.executable = sys.executable.replace('flask_demo\\App', 'flask_demo\\..\\..\\App')

    app = create_app()
    host = 'localhost'
    port = 5000
    CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": ["http://localhost:3000"]}})
    app.run(debug=True, host=host, port=port)
    # serve(app, host=host, port=port)



def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/api/id_mode')
    def hello_world():
        return jsonify({
            "status": "success",
            "message": "Hello World!"
        })

    return app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**requirements.txt**:

```
flask==2.3.2
flask-cors==3.0.10
```

Next.js application defined in **_app.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import App from 'next/app';

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const parameters = { ...pageProps };
  return <Component {...parameters} />;
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  const appProperties = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);

  async function apiCall(){
    const url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/id_mode'
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const text = await response.text();
    return text;

  }

  const extraProperty = await apiCall()

  return {
    ...appProperties,
    extraProperty
  };
};
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';

export default function Index(properties) {

  return <>{"Hello from next.js"}</>;
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "flask_demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "13.4.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "7.0.3"
  }
}
```

Output in Network tab:

[image]

Related:

[PyCharm runs a flask app but fails to debug it in python3.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76242327/pycharm-runs-a-flask-app-but-fails-to-debug-it-in-python3-11/76263800#76263800)

[next.js fetch request gives error TypeError: fetch failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74165121/next-js-fetch-request-gives-error-typeerror-fetch-failed)

Comment: What response do you see in network tab from server?

Comment: I improved the question to include example code. I also included the output of the network tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` in the url for the fetch command in the next.js front end fixed the issue.

First I missed the fact, that when updating WinPython, I did not only update python from 3.10.5 to 3.11.1, but also updated the node version from v16.16.0 to v18.12.1.

Then I found the related question [next.js fetch request gives error TypeError: fetch failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74165121/next-js-fetch-request-gives-error-typeerror-fetch-failed)

It's interesting that `localhost` does work when using waitress `serve` function instead of `app.run`. I guess that the two approaches to start flask rely on different implementations regarding `localhost` vs `127.0.0.1`.